# ASP.net core 3.1: Serializing a list in model and deserializing in JavaScript

Tags: json, asp.net-core, serialization, deserialization, razor-pages

I'm trying to get a list of objects from the model and use it in JavaScript. What is the best method of serializing the List in the Model and deserializing it in the JavaScript code so I can loop through the list in JS? I should be able to save the list in a JavaScript variable.

Model List:

```
public List<Post> postsList { get; set; }
```

If you can provide the specific code that would be perfect.

Answer (score 1):

In MVC it is done in a straightforward way (using strongly-typed view or just ViewBag).
Let's assume u have 2 models - FooViewModel:

```
    public class FooViewModel
{
    public int FooId { get; set; }
    public List<BarViewModel> Bars { get; } = new List<BarViewModel>();
}
```

and BarViewModel:

```
 public class BarViewModel
{
    public int BarId { get; set; }

    public string BarName { get; set; }

    public string BarTitle { get; set; }

    public int IdFooViewModel { get; set; }
}
```

Default HomeController have been changed a little bit:

```
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        var vm = new FooViewModel
        {
            FooId = 1,
            Bars =
            {
                new BarViewModel {BarId = 1, BarName = "First Bar", BarTitle = "I am here!", IdFooViewModel = 1},
                new BarViewModel {BarId = 2, BarName = "Second Bar", BarTitle = "Me too!", IdFooViewModel = 1}
            }
        };
        return View(vm);
    }
```

On a razor backend we construct a javascript object:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}
@using System.Collections.Specialized
@using System.Text.Json
@model FooViewModel

<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Index works!</p>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    <script>
        var vm = window.viewModel = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model))');
        console.dir(vm);
    </script>
}
```

Please, notice `@Html.Raw` tag helper is used reasonably - razor does html-encoding, which corrupts quotation marks of json data. That's why we get rid of html-encoding. But this can be  security critical - your client should trust your backend.

Then, client side does deserialize long string literal to get data.

[image: Result]]

Comment: I serialized the list in the model using: public string postSerialized { get; set; }  and  postSerialized = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(postsList); in the OnGet method. But when i try to deserialize the string in javascript using var obj = JSON.parse(@Model.postSerialized);   its not working. What am i doing wrong. Note: i want to loop through the obj.

Comment: You should wrap @Model.postSerialized with single quotes - JSON.parse deserializes from a string, i.e. it should be string literal. In your way it is unknown identifier in js code. Try to do exactly the same way as in example above - it works. After getting it worked try to view source code in your browser - u will see this string literal.

Comment: Tried the single quotes and the following error is shown: caught SyntaxError: Unexpected token & in JSON at position 2
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Nearby:557

Comment: var obj = JSON.parse('@Model.postSerialized');
    console.log(obj);

Comment: And where is `@Html.Raw` here? Please read carefully every answer's sentence.

Comment: Thank you for the help, but its throwing a Syntax error, my code is : 
var obj = JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(@Model.postsList))');
    console.log(obj);  
     Error: VM67:1 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token i in JSON at position 256 at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Nearby:557